# Use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var with GitHub Actions secret

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

My problem is simple: I want to run code that depends on `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` being set up correctly from a GitHub Actions secret.

The problem is that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is expect to contain a path to a service account file, whether the secret contain the actual service account file content.

What's the best practice for that?

---

**EDIT**

Essentially I run a NodeJS script which connect to multiple GCP resources using client libraries (PubSub, BigQuery, etc). To my understanding, they can most easily work if `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var is correctly defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is that GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is expect to
> contain a path to a service account file, whether the secret contain
> the actual service account file content.

There isn't one. The environment variable must point to a file which is the location for a service account JSON key. You could write the contents to an artifact, but that is dangerous. There are other methods, but your question does not provide details on what your GitHub action does or the commands it runs. However, I still would not use those methods.

The correct solution is to use Google Cloud Workload Identity Federation. That is both the solution and the best practice solution.

GitHub provides an OAuth identity provider. Google supports federating credentials from one OAuth provider to another.

[Enabling keyless authentication from GitHub Actions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions)

[google-github-actions/auth](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth)

Comment: See my edit please, maybe it'll shed more light.

Comment: The answer provided by @kornshell93 is the artifact method that I mentioned in my answer. You asked for best practice, not just any solution regardless of security implications.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [this](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#authenticating-via-service-account-key-json-1) GitHub action to log in. Pretty much you have to create a secret with the content of the service account and specified it as input:

```
    - id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
      with:
        credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}'
```

Comment: My understanding is that it's better to use the Workload Identity Federation approach.

https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#setting-up-workload-identity-federation

Comment: that's correct @nstanard

Comment: thanks it helps me finally get the Google auth.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible workaround in Python:

```py
def get_credentials_from_env_variables():
    creds_list = [
        "TYPE",
        "PROJECT_ID",
        "PRIVATE_KEY_ID",
        "PRIVATE_KEY",
        "CLIENT_EMAIL",
        "CLIENT_ID",
        "AUTH_URI",
        "TOKEN_URI",
        "AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL",
        "CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL",
        "UNIVERSE_DOMAIN",
    ]

    creds_dict = {}
    for cred in creds_list:
        loaded_cred = os.getenv(cred)
        creds_dict[cred.lower()] = loaded_cred.encode().decode("unicode_escape")

    # Create a temporary file
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w+", delete=False) as temp_file:
        temp_filename = temp_file.name
        json.dump(creds_dict, temp_file)

    # Load credentials from the temporary file
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(temp_filename)

    # Remove the temporary file
    os.remove(temp_filename)

    return credentials
```

In short, use env variables to create temp credentials in JSON